# formula for charge on an electron

Tags: excel, physics

Can someone take a look at my equation and let me know if you see the error?

Here are two screenshots of cells that are used:

**cells of constants1**
[image: cells of constants1]
and

**cells of data used**
[image]

My equation for the radius seems to be working fine:

`=SQRT((Constants!D2/2*Constants!E2)^2+(9*Constants!I2*G2/2*Constants!C2*Constants!B2))-(Constants!D2/2*Constants!E2)`

I'm getting values between 5.34E-09 and 1.12E-08 meters.

However my charge equation is not working:

`=(4/3)*PI*Constants!B2*Constants!C2*(SQRT((Constants!D2/2*Constants!E2)^2+9*Constants!I2*G2/2*Constants!C2*Constants!B2)-Constants!D2/2*Constants!E2)^3*(G2+H2)/Constants!J2*G2`

The equation for radius is:

radEq
[image]

And the equation for charge is:

chargeEQ
[image]

Please let me know if any values need clarification.

Comment: *'I hate Excel... Mathematica is life'* That's a paradox.

Comment: haha how so?! mathematica is so beautiful!

Comment: Was there an expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=(4/3)*PI()*Constants!B2*Constants!C2*(SQRT((Constants!D2/2*Constants!E2)^2+9*Constants!I2*G2/2*Constants!C2*Constants!B2)-Constants!D2/2*Constants!E2)^3*(G2+H2)/Constants!J2*G2
```